# I've really got confused with children and childNodes in JS

Tags: javascript, dom, children

Look at this part of html:

```
 <table id="Table">
    <tr>
       <td><img src="Sample Pics/Koala.jpg""></td>
       <td><img src="Sample Pics/Desert.jpg"></td>
       <td><img src="Sample Pics/Fall.jpg"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><*img src="Sample Pics/Fish.jpg"></td>
       <td><img src="Sample Pics/Fresh Fruit Platter.jpg"></td>
       <td><img src="Sample Pics/Hydrangeas.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the (for example) *image source via js.
i know it would be something like:

```
document.getElementById("Table").children[?].BlahBlahBlah.src = "New Source";
```

But i have no idea about it.

Is there some places o learn about children? i looked through W3Schools.com but i found nothing useful.

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children

Answer (score 2):

> I've really got confused with children and childNodes

The difference between them is that while `children` only contain the child *element* nodes ("tags"), `childNodes` also contain text nodes (and a few more, like comments etc). Since many childNodes are empty/whitespace-only text nodes, that property are not very useful for DOM traversal. Use it only if you're really interested in the text.

> I want to change the (for example) *image source via js

For tables, there is also the [`.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.rows) collection that provides convenient access to all rows in the different table sections. Each of [those row elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) also has a `.cells` collection, so that you can access your image as

```
document.getElementById("Table").rows[1].cells[0].children[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
var table = document.getElementById("Table");
```

Then:

- `table.children` returns a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) containing the child *elements* (`HTMLCollection[tbody]`)
- `table.childNodes` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/NodeList) containing all child *nodes* (including, for example, text nodes, as well as the elements (`NodeList[<TextNode textContent="\n ">, tbody]`))

You might actually prefer to retrieve the target `td` more directly:

```
table.getElementsByTagName("td")[3]
```

Or even:

```
table.getElementsByTagName("img")[3]
```